# get "Segmentation fault" when use pyscipopt addConsOr

Tags: scip

I tried to use pyscipopt `addConsOr` but got *Segmentation fault* error. I want to add a constraint for two integers with `x != y`. If use

```
    x = model.addVar("x", "I")
    y = model.addVar("y", "I")
    model.addCons(x != y)
```

there is an error message,

> NotImplementedError: Can only support constraints with '<=', '>=', or '=='.

If use `addConsOr` to implement `x != y`, there is "Segmentation fault" error.

```
   x = model.addVar("x", "I")
   y = model.addVar("y", "I")
   r = model.addVar("r", "B")
   model.addConsOr([x>=y+1, x<=y-1],r)
```

How can I fix the error? Is there any better way to add constraint for `x != y` ? Thanks.